# Kendo MVC Grid editable cascading dropdown showing 'undefined'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to follow along with the Telerik demo for cascading dropdowns, but so far I have had no luck. Here is the demo that I am trying to use: [Telerik Demo - Cascading DropDownList](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist?_ga=2.19809080.100080375.1583167103-1861425001.1582221191)
My problem is that when I filter contacts based off of the `ModelId` (I have a different name than this), I am getting the dropdown just saying 'undefined'

Here is my grid code (the parts that matter)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-clickable-edit" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit().IconClass("fas fa-pencil").UpdateIconClass("fas fa-check").CancelIconClass("fas fa-ban");
            command.Destroy().IconClass("fas fa-trash");
        })
            .ClientHeaderTemplate(Html.GridAddButton())
            .Width(180);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ModelId)
            .EditorTemplateName("GridDropdownEditor")
            .EditorViewData(new { data = ViewBag.ModelList })
            .ClientTemplate("#:ModelName#");
        columns.Bound(p => p.ContactId)
            .EditorTemplateName("ContactCascadingDropdown")
            .ClientTemplate("#:ContactName#");
    })
    .Pageable(pg => pg.Numeric(false).PreviousNext(false))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Virtual(true))
    .Filterable(x => x.Enabled(false))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model => { model.Id(m => m.MyId); })
        .Read(...)
        .Create(...)
        .Update(...)
        .Destroy(...)
    ))

<script>
    function filterContacts() {
        return {
            modelId: $("#ModelId").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Here is my `ContactCascadingDropdown` editor template -

```
@model object

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataTextField("ContactName")
    .DataValueField("ContactId")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCascadingContacts", "ControllerName")
                .Data("filterContacts");
        })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .Enable(false)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .CascadeFrom("ModelId"))
```

`GetCascadingContacts` method from `MyController` -

```
public JsonResult GetCascadingContacts(int? modelId)
{
      var contacts = _contact.GetListQueryable();

      if (contacts != null)
      {
            contacts = contacts.Where(c => c.ModelId == modelId);
      }

      return Json(contacts.Select(c => new {ContactName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName, c.ContactId}));
}
```

I believe the problem is probably the editor template, but again, I don't really have an idea.

**What I've tried**
Checked the web browser console for errors, none found 
Checked for error output in Visual Studio, none found 
I also made sure that the `modelId` value was actually getting passed from my `filterContacts` method to my controller, which is was. Also checked to see if the Contacts query method was pulling actual contacts based off the `modelId` which it was.

**UPDATE**
Seems like the number of lines I am getting in the dropdown correlates to the amount of Contacts I get back from the query.

**UPDATE**
If I add the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` that the demo calls for to make my return statment `return Json(contacts.Select(c => new {ContactName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName, c.ContactId}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`, then I get the error 
`Property 'JsonResult.SerializerSettings' must be an instance of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'.`

Answer (score 0):

This structure worked for me when I tried something similar in a project of mine:

Change:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ContactId)
            .EditorTemplateName("ContactCascadingDropdown")
            .ClientTemplate("#:ContactName#");
```

to:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.ContactId, Model.Contacts, "ContactId", "ContactName")
             .EditorTemplateName("ContactCascadingDropdown")
             .Title("Contact")
```

What is happening above?

- We use a foreign key to the template
- We define what the value of the column will be `p -> p.ContactId`
- We pass a list of contact information, using the ID and value of the list (in this case `ContactId` and `ContactName`)

My EditorTemplate looks something like this:

```
@model int

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .AutoBind(true)
    .DataTextField("ContactName")
    .DataValueField("ContactId")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read => read.Action("GetCascadingContacts", "ControllerName")
            .Data("filterContacts")).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .CascadeFrom("ModelId")

    // If this value could be a nullable you will also need the following
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
)
```

The return of your controller method should be:

```
return Json(contacts.Select(c => new {ContactName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName, c.ContactId}), JsonRequestBehavior.Allowget);
```

Comment: Followed your example, and it does not seem to be working for me. The first error that I have is `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`. What is the point of the `Mode.Contacts` in the ContactId column? ie what does it do exactly? Also, like I said in my update on my post, I get a confliction with `System.Web.Mvc` and `Newtonsoft.Json` when I add in `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that instead of returning `ContactName` and `ContactId`, the Json that Kendo was returning was `contactName` and `contactId`. I figured this out by using the network tab in the browser dev tools and seeing the returned data. Here is the fixed and working version:

```
@model object

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataTextField("contactName")
    .DataValueField("contactId")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCascadingContacts", "ControllerName")
                .Data("filterContacts");
        })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .Enable(false)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .CascadeFrom("ModelId"))
```